# Trying to get second row from DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm trying to retrieve the second row from a DataTable but this is not returning a value. What could be the problem as the DropDown populates just fine.

```
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                DropDown.DataSource = dt;
                DropDown.DataTextField = "FirstName";
                DropDown.DataValueField = "FirstName";
                DropDown.DataBind();
                con.Close();

                var secondRow = dt.Rows[2].ToString(); // This should return the second row in my datatable.
            }
```

Comment: I believe that actually returns your third row. `DataTables`/`DataRows` start their counting at `0` (along with many other things). Also, try adding a `break point` and making sure your `DataTable` is actually being filled

Comment: You're correct about that but regardless of what value I put there it's returning "System.Data.DataRow" and not the value

Comment: @Shane You're calling `ToString` on an instance of `System.Data.DataRow`, so it's returning the type name because there's no override for `ToString` on that type. That's expected behavior. What information are you trying to get from the data row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataTable.Rows[int]` will give you the `DataRow` object. If you do `dt.Rows[2].ToString()`, you are going to get the string representation of the object type.

The index starts at `0`. Hence for 2nd row, you will query `dt.Rows[1]`. Further, You can extract the value of a column in the row and for that, you have to mention the column index or name like - `dt.Rows[1][0]` or `dt.Rows[1]["col1"]`

You can also loop through all the columns in the row like below:

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
  var columnValue = dt.Rows[1][col];
}
```